# Checking number of CUDA cores from visual profiler

Tags: gpu, profiling, nvidia

How can you check the number of CUDA cores that are being used from the NVIDIA Visual Profiler? I have the image below taken from the Visual Profiler. Is it just based on the number of "Thread" objects on the left side?

[image]

Comment: These threads are for launching work on the gpu and are running on CPU. You can look at Analysis tab followed by Compute Utilization tab to get an idea of how much of your GPU is being used.

Comment: @instinct71 thanks for your response! Why are the threads being launched for work on the gpu but then running on CPU though?

Comment: The Driver/Runtime API under the threads tells that the threads are driver/runtime related work. Your actual cuda kernels will be under a tab called compute which would be under a tab with your GPU name like "Tesla--xxx".

Comment: @instinct71 Sorry I just got to this, but I can't seem to find the Compute Utilization Tab? Are you referring to NVIDIA Visual Profiler?